# Como hago para que los submenus aparezcan progresivamente

Tags: html, css

He creado un pequeño ejemplo para enseñaroslo haber si alguien puede ayudarme, mi problema es que tengo un menu nav con un li articulos el cual despliega un submenu, me gustaria que este apareciera progresivamente al hacer hover en articulos, el problema es que no se como hacer para mezclar display none y block con la propiedad opacity, si solo pongo la propiedad opacity y una transiccion de 2 segundos hace el efecto que quiero el problema esta en que necesito utilizar el display none porque sino los elementos del submenu son clickables aunque su opacidad sea 0, no creo que sea muy dificil hacerlo pero la verdad es que me esta dando un quebradero de cabeza, os dejo aqui el codigo.

```
introducir el código aquí

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>prueba opacity</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navegador_izquierda" class="navegadores">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ACTUALIDAD</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">QUIENES SOMOS</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">EVENTOS</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">ARTICULOS</a>
                <ul id="desplegable_articulos">
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categoria 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>



*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav{
    background: red;
}

nav > ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
}

nav > ul > li > ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 2s; 
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li{
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav > ul > li > ul >li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Aca te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo solo usando `html` y `css` [Menú Desplegable](https://codepen.io/epjuan21/pen/zxPmYxT)

Comment: el enlace me lleva a una pagina 404 de codepen

Comment: https://codepen.io/epjuan21/pen/zxPmYx

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel